# HTTP redirects in the AWS world, anything better than S3+CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm moving my domain names from CloudFlare's DNS to AWS Route53 and in some cases I'm using CloudFlare's redirects for project that are dead so that their domains go to a page in another domain, so `https://projectx.com` goes to `https://example.com/projectx-is-no-more`.

I want to replicate this in AWS and what I found so far is this:

1. Set up an S3 bucket with the redirect to the desired URL, `https://example.com/projectx-is-no-more`
2. Set up CloudFront for the domain, `projectx.com`
3. Generate the TLS cert for projectx.com and add it to CloudFront so it can serve both https and http.
4. Set up Route53 to resolve the domain name to CloudFront.

I set it up, it's working, I'm even using CDK so I'm not doing it manually. But I'm wondering if there's a way of setting up these redirects that requires less moving pieces. It sounds like such a redirect would be a common enough problem that maybe Route53 or CloudFront would have a shortcut. Are there any?

Update: using only S3 doesn't work because S3 cannot serve `https://projectx.com`. S3 has no method by which it can respond to HTTPS request for arbitrary domains, there's no way of adding a TLS certificate (and keys) for another domain.

Comment: The simplest solution is to set same for IP for `example.com` and `projectx.com` and handle two domain names on same server (this is not problem for Apache or Nginx web servers). If this is not possible S3 way looking cheapest and solid. Also it is possible to do redirects with application load balancer (ALB) but ALB is pretty expensive in conparison with tiny static `index.html` uploaded to S3.

Comment: In this case, `example.com` is a WordPress running in `wordpress.com`, so I don't have a good control over any redirects there (and generally supporting more domains may cost money).

Comment: I was little bit wrong about S3 features. So did answer after check info at the internet

Comment: I added GitHub solution to my answer. If you don't have any business side restrictions to use other platforms, that will be a killer feature.

Answer (score 1):

I checked for information and see only three possible solutions:

1. Set up [CloudFront + S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) *
2. Set up [Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-to-another-domain-with-alb/)
3. Set up [API Gateway + Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/compute/redirection-in-a-serverless-api-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) ([mock integration](https://forum.serverless.com/t/how-to-redirect-path-to-external-resource-aws/10353) may be used instead of Lambda, that should reduce service cost)
4. Use [GitHub pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages) with [custom domain](https://hossainkhan.medium.com/using-custom-domain-for-github-pages-86b303d3918a)

※ S3 support only HTTP traffic so we need to add CloudFront for HTTPS:

> Amazon S3 does not support HTTPS access to the website. If you want to use HTTPS, you can use Amazon CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3.

In my opinion the ②nd way is super easy to set up but running 24/7 ALB is little bit expensive. In other way Lambda and API Gateway [price](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/?nc1=h_ls) depending on requests count. CloudFront seems to be [cheaper](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/ap2haa/cloudfront_cheaper_than_alb/) than ALB too.

So the better solution is depending on how many requests you have

The ④th solution is depends on GitHub platform (wider than AWS only scope), but it is **absolutely free** and support custom domain and Let's Encrypt certificates out of the box.
You just need to create repository with static `index.html` file that will do redirects

Comment: Lambda isn't required with API Gateway if the redirect is a static fixed response. You can use a mock integration with a fixed response body.

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar Yes you are correct. I didn't know full features of mock integrations but looks like it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without including CloudFront.

What you need to do is create S3 bucket `projectx.com`. In `Properties` go to `Static website hosting`. Enable static website hosting and choose `Redirect` as a hosting type (add the redirection URL).

You will still need to set up Route53, but you will now add alias to this `projectx.com` bucket, instead of going to CloudFront

Comment: Wouldn't that be missing support for https? Sorry, I should have mentioned I need support for http and https in the question.

Comment: You can choose the protocol: 
Protocol - Optional
none
http
https

Comment: That's the target protocol. There's no way to have an S3 bucket server https://projectx.com. S3 cannot serve a third party TLS certificate.

Comment: I don't care who issues it, as long as it's for projectx.com (and it's an issuer known by the browsers of course).